# Boost process stream is empty

Tags: c++, boost

I just installed the Boost library and I am trying to get through the basic tutorial.

I am trying to open a process that runs `g++ --version` and pipes the output to std_`std_out`.

The code is copied from the [tutorial](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html) with the following changes:

- added `cout` statements to track progress
- added call to `bp::find_executable_in_path()`

Here's the code:

```
//
// Boost.Process
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2006, 2007 Julio M. Merino Vidal
// Copyright (c) 2008 Boris Schaeling
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = ::boost::process;
using namespace std;

bp::child start_child() {
    string exec = bp::find_executable_in_path( "g++" );
    cout << "full path is " << exec << endl;

    cout << "starting child process" << endl;
    vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back( "--version" );

    bp::context ctx;
    ctx.stdout_behavior = bp::capture_stream();
    ctx.stderr_behavior = bp::capture_stream();

    return bp::launch( exec, args, ctx );
}

int main() {
    bp::child c = start_child();

    bp::pistream &is = c.get_stdout();
    cout << ( is ? "stream is valid" : "stream is NOT valid" ) << endl;
    string line;
    cout << "entering read/write loop" << endl;
    while( getline( is, line ) ) {
        cout << "copying a line" << endl;
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    cout << "exiting read/write loop" << endl;
}
```

Here is what I see when I run `g++ --version` on the command line:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This is the output of the compiled program:

```
full path is /usr/bin/g++
starting child process
stream is valid
entering read/write loop
exiting read/write loop
```

It never enters the read/write loop. What happened to the data from the stream?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the full path to gcc, or use `bp::find_executable_in_path("g++")`

[edit]  oops. Under windows:

`bp::find_executable_in_path("g++.exe")`

Comment: I tried that. The stream is still empty, I've updated the code in the OP.